# How to handle dates with 30 days per month in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, date, date-formatting

I am currently working with a dataset in which every month has 30 days (including February). This causes problems converting with `pd.datetime()`. Does pandas have some built in function or setting that allows to work with 30 days per month? I looked for it, but didn't find anything. Maybe I simply missed a keyword that I should have specifically searched for.

An example:
My dataset contains entries like this:

```
1950-02-30 19:00:00  11.799651  57.780991  0.114197
1950-02-30 20:00:00  11.799651  57.780991  0.113489
1950-02-30 21:00:00  11.799651  57.780991  0.138634
1950-02-30 22:00:00  11.799651  57.780991  0.167683
1950-02-30 23:00:00  11.799651  57.780991  0.197449
```

Due to the 30th February not existing in a normal calendar (obviously) I can not convert the dates with `pd.datetime()`. The normal datetime format normally comes in handy to determine things like the daily maximum.

Comment: What does "every month has 30 days" mean? Is that some financial format or something? [non-Gregorian calendar](http://www.webexhibits.org/calendars/calendar-ancient.html)? [Iranian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iranian_calendars)? Anyway you can always a) handle those dates as strings, without converting to datetimes, or b) unpack them into three separate columns `year`, `month`, `day`; now they will sort correctly. Show us a code example with data snippet to explain where you're stuck.

Comment: Added an example for you. It is some model data, where every month has 30 days.

Comment: I honestly have not seen Feb 30 as a date throughout my career. You must be using some very specialized tool that utilized such format. One way is to decouple the month and the day into 2 columns: `Month = 1950-02, Day = 30`. What are you trying to do with the dates?

Comment: You have to describe a more specific issue than *"This causes problems while working"*. I already explained in comment above how to avoid problems: either a) keep dates as strings, without converting to datetimes, or b) unpack them into three separate columns `year`, `month`, `day`. Both those will work. I'd do b). Explain why b) does not work for you (add a code example, and show why the output is bad).

Comment: So don't use `pd.datetime()`. Write your own function that unpacks a '%Y-%m-%d' format string to three columns `year`, `month`, `day`.

Comment: Like [Convert datetime string to new columns of Day, Month, Year in pandas data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41455967/convert-datetime-string-to-new-columns-of-day-month-year-in-pandas-data-frame). Please confirm that solves your issue.

Comment: Or, option a) was just leave the datestring as a string (and use it as the index if you like) Since you're using Y-M-D format, it'll still sort in-order. pandas just won't be able to do much with it like date arithmetic, between(), ranges etc.